# Publishing/Deploying Orchard CMS 1.8 with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, visual-studio-2013, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I am new to Orchard 1.8 and have developed a website using Visual Studio Premium 2013 Version 12.0.21005.1 (with the .NET 4.5.51641 Framework) and I need to know how to Publish/Deploy an Orchard website from a local desktop development box to an in-house "production" machine that has Windows Server 21012 R2, and IIS 8.5.

The development version of the site (on my local machine) uses SQL Server 2012 SP1 as the database.

How do I Publish/Deploy to the in-house "production" machine that has: Windows Server 21012 R2, and IIS 8.5 and specify another "production" database (which will need the data from the development version transferred to it)?

I am also new to publishing/deploying using VS. I would like to use "File System" as the Publish method, if possible.

Any detailed steps/instructions on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When using "File System" method you can just copy paste the output of the publish package to the server. Your db settings are to be defined in the web.config.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Pardon my ignorance, where would I find the publish package and what would it look like? Also I first thought that the DB settings would be a <connectionStrings> setting in the web.config, however they aren't there in the development version. It seems that Orchard 1.8 is using settings in Orchard.Web\App_Data\Sites\Default\Settings.txt. So my first assumption was I could change it there. Would that be correct? - Thanks!

Comment: You are correct. Db settings are in `Orchard.Web\App_Data\Sites\Default\Settings.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You're right about needing to change settings.txt not web.config for the database connection string.

For the remaining steps, this answer assumes that you're developing from the Orchard Source, so you can run `build precompiled` from a developer command prompt. Here is an overview of the steps:

1. **Configure IIS 8.5** on the server the same way that you configured it on your local desktop. You'll need to configure the application pools, for instance, and also make sure you have ASP.NET enabled.
2. **Backup your local database and restore it on the production** SQL Server. You will also need to configure security for the application pool.
3. **Make a [`precompiled build`](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Building-and-deploying-Orchard-from-a-source-code-drop)** of your Orchard CMS.
4. **Make a new website in IIS** on your production server.
5. **Copy and paste the build results from step 3 into the root directly** of the website from step 4. Set all the Access Control permissions for App_Data, Media, Themes, and Modules, as needed.
6. **Change the settings.txt file** to point at the new database.

You will be good to go unless you face some gotchas. You might also need to bring access your Media folder, if it contains images or other static resources to which your site links, and maybe your Theme too.

Comment: I was partially successful getting the site up to the server. One of the things missing is the page layout selector. We install DownPlay Design’s Layout Selector - 0.3; which adds a DDL to select a layout for pages. It works fine on the Dev box. However, even thought the module shows as installed and the code seems to be in the Modules folder on the production server, when one edits a page, the DDL to select the layout does not appear in the page editor.

Comment: I have never used the DownPlay module. Have you successfully installed any other modules from the Orchard Gallery? In other words, is the issue specific to the DownPlay module or is it happening with other Gallery modules too? If you aren't sure, I would try to install another simple module from the Gallery and check whether it works in production.

Comment: Also, have you checked the Orchard logs for error messages? You can find these in `Orchard.Web\App_Data\Logs`. Sometimes they're very helpful in troubleshooting.

Comment: I figured it out. There was not any error messages in the Orchard logs. But when SQL Profiler was run, it did indicate that it the choices for layouts was not being selected. I deleted the DownPlay Design’s Layout Selector's folder from the production server. That allowed me to re-install it and then it worked. Go figure!

Comment: Now I have a new issue. There were some changes to the site on the Dev box. When I try to publish the site, it's not transferring the complete set of site folder to the production server. There is only. Folder tree

|    - Global.asax

|    - Local_A1_Website_Publish_DirList.txt

|    - Refresh.html
|    - Web.config
+_ bin  
+_ Config

+_ Proccess

The rest of the site folders, i.e. Themes, Media, Modules, etc. did not get created. Don't know what it's different from the first publish.

Comment: I started a new question with more details regarding the above issue at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693618/publishing-deploying-orchard-cms-1-8-w-visual-studio-2013-not-all-files-are-t