# Publishing/Deploying Orchard CMS 1.8 w/ Visual Studio 2013 - Not all files are transfered to server

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, visual-studio-2013, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

This is a follow-up issue regarding [Publishing/Deploying Orchard CMS 1.8 with Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25407302/publishing-deploying-orchard-cms-1-8-with-visual-studio-2013)

I am new to Orchard 1.8 and have developed a website using Visual Studio Premium 2013 Version 12.0.21005.1 (with the .NET 4.5.51641 Framework) and I need to know how to Publish/Deploy an Orchard website from a local desktop development box to an in-house "production" machine that has Windows Server 21012 R2, and IIS 8.5.

The development version of the site (on my local machine) uses SQL Server 2012 SP1 as the database.

I was able to deploy once and get beyond the issue sited above.

There were some changes to the site on the Dev box. When I try to publish the site, it's not transferring the complete set of site folder to the production server. There is only the following.

```
Folder tree for new publish: 
|    - Global.asax
|    - Local_A1_Website_Publish_DirList.txt
|    - Refresh.html
|    - Web.config
+_ bin
+_ Config
+_ Proccess
```

The original was

```
Folder tree for the original publish:
    |    - Global.asax
    |    - Refresh.html
    |    - Web.config
    +_ App_Data
    +_ bin
    +_ Config
    +_ Core
    +_ Media
    +_ Modules
    +_ Proccess
    +_ Themes
```

Don't know what it's different from the first publish. Can I just copy this from the dev box to the production server. If not how do I get a complete set of the folder structure to be published?

Thanks in advance.

If it will help the .pubxml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This file is used by the publish/package process of your Web project. You can customize the behavior of this process
by editing this MSBuild file. In order to learn more about this please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>\\server\folder</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>False</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: How do you publish your site? The easiest way IMO to deploy your website is in VS to choose Publish, then choose the file publish method. After that just copy the output to your website root.

Comment: In VS 2013, I am using Publish and the file system method. But as mentioned above, I am seeing a difference between the file structure.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this problem.  We have a build configuration that does copy all of the files in the web directory, but any new configurations (copies of the working config) seem to be missing the same exact files groups you have listed above.

Answer (score 1):

Well, figured this out.

1. Right click on the Orchard.Web project and go to Properties.
2. Select the Package/Publish Web tab on the left.
3. Make sure the build configuration is the config you are using to deploy.
4. Under the Items To Deploy section, the dropdown should say "All files in this
   project", not "only files needed to run this application".

[image]